# is there a way to prefill sms message body

Tags: firefox-os

Are there any ways to pre-fill the SMS message body by using web activities?
My application is not certified and I cannot use websms api to send messages.

Comment: Pre-fill message body of what? Please explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Ok. I have one button and on that button event like this: var parkpg2 = document.querySelector("#parkpg2"); if (parkpg2) { parkpg2.onclick = function () { var sms = new MozActivity({ name: "new", data: { type: "websms/sms", number: "14552" window.localStorage['plateNumber'] } }); } } As You can see, number to send sms to is prefilled like "number: "14552"," and now I want to prefill message body for example: "Hello world!" Thank You!

Comment: You should add your current code in the question, showing what you have done so far if you expect an answer

Answer (score 4):

The property you are looking for is probably the `body` property on the `mozActivity` options object. Here is the code from the [bugzilla bug 852224](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=852224#c5) in which this feature was implemented:

```
new MozActivity({
  name: 'new',
  data: {
    type: 'websms/sms',
    number: '999',
    body: 'hi!'
  }
});
```

*Please note, that I tried this code on latest stock firmware of the Keon Firefox OS developer phone, but it doesn't seem to work for the body - that might be because this firmware version (1.0.1.0, build id.:20130712192650) might doesn't yet include this fix.*