# How can I send SMS from Firefox OS web app when 3rd party apps can't be certified?

Tags: firefox-os

I am creating a simple app that in the end should send SMS message.

Mozilla docs state that only certified apps can access WebSMS API which I understand is used to send SMS.

Docs also state that certified app status isn't intended for 3rd party apps in app store.

Is there any other way other than using WebSMS API to send an SMS message. I don't need SMS to be sent in completely automatic manner - I would be happy if I can insert SMS contents into new SMS form and let user send it themselves.

Comment: I have a similar question. I want to develop an app, which will send a SMS automatically after an event occurred. Can I send an SMS automatically ? Or there is not anyway to send SMS automatically ?
Thanks

Comment: You can if your app is certified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prefill an SMS message, see: [is there a way to prefill sms message body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659596/is-there-a-way-to-prefill-sms-message-body).  It doesn't work in the simulator and seems to only be supported in the newest version of the OS though.

Also here's a link to all the activities you can supposedly do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Web_Activities